# Transferring information from repeated section to repeated grid on Orbeon with XForms

Tags: forms, xpath, orbeon, xforms

On my form I have a repeated section, that has text fields firstname, lastname and age (among others). I also have a button.

You fill out those text fields (firstname, lastname and age), and add them as many times as you want on with the repeated section. I want that when you push the button, all of the information from those fields copy to a repeated grid.

For example, if I have filled out two repeated sections, each having two first names, two last names and two ages. Then I click the button and the information on those text fields copy to a repeated grid that will have two rows and the same fields (first name, last name and age) with the information I have given.

**I would like to do this on the form, with XForms, xpath and other. Is this possible, without any custom http service?** I am using Orbeon 2016. The repeated grid already has those 3 text fields, I just want the button to add rows (depending on the amount of repeated sections and information given) and copy the given texts from those 3 text fields in the repeated section.

Comment: That's definitely possible by writing custom XForms. It takes a bit of work to get that kind of code right, though: it involves event handlers and running XForms actions as needed.

Comment: @ebruchez I know, I have done something similar but I had a http service so the XForms was pretty straight forward. That’s why I’m asking how to do it without a service because I don’t have one now.